# Implementing transactions over multiple databases

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, transactions

I am performing data changes on multiple databases, and I want to implement a transaction that will cover all of the changes.

This is what I currently have:

```cs
try
{
    db[1].begintransaction();
    db[1].ExecuteNonQuery();

    db[2].begintransaction();
    db[2].ExecuteNonQuery();

    ...

    db[N].begintransaction();
    db[N].ExecuteNonQuery();

    // will execute only if no exception raised during the process
    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++)
    {
        db[a].Commit();// what if there is an error/exception here
    }
}
catch
{
    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++)
    {
        db[a].RollBack();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the above would fail horribly if an exception happens during a `Commit()` (see the comment). Is there any better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Note: this is not the actual code. ive modified it significantly for clarity

Comment: Hey i'm having the same issue... And my databases can be either Mysql and Sql Server... Will it work with TransactionScope?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class like this:

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    //all db code here

    // if an error occurs jump out of the using block and it will dispose and rollback

    ts.Complete();
}
```

The TransactionScope class will automatically convert to a distributed transaction if necessary.

Comment: @Jesse, I think for transaction across databases, even in latest version of .Net, Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator will be needed. I couldn't get why you said it will not be needed?

Comment: @Sunil You are totally right. It was a misunderstanding on my part of the .NET Framework at the time. I will proceed to remove the erroneous comment. Thanks for notifying me! =)

Answer (score 1):

Using transactionScope is the answer. It even works with different DBMS!!!

[Transactions over multiple databases](http://blogs.interakting.co.uk/post/Transactions-over-multiple-databases.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As cletus said, you need some kind of [two-phase commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase%5Fcommit%5Fprotocol). As the article states, this doesn't always work in practice. If you need a robust solution, you must find a way to serialize the transactions in such a way that you can do them one after the other and roll them back individually.

Since this depends on the specific case on which you don't provide any details, I can't give you ideas how to attack this.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to execute transaction across multiple instances of SQL Server then take a look at the [Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684146(VS.85).aspx) documentation