# Modifying multiple databases in one transaction - no TransactionScope

Tags: c#, database, transactions

I know I can use TransactionScope - [Implementing transactions over multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063502/how-to-implement-transaction-over-multiple-databases)

But there are classes `TransactionManager` and `Transaction` having methods for enlisting durable and volatile transactions and for recovery. However I can't find good code examples of how to use it. I don't know if they give something else then TransactionScope. Can you explain what are differences? When to use which? And do You have any code examples?

Comment: Why not TransactionScope, out of curiosity?