# Is it possible to use OleDbTransaction to save data in two different databases?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, oracle9i, distributed-transactions

Using C#, is it possible to use `OleDbTransaction` to execute a insert in two different database vendors, such as **Microsoft SQL Server** and **Oracle**?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063502/how-to-implement-transaction-over-multiple-databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Is it possible to use OleDbTransaction to save data in two different databases?

No because an `OleDbTransaction` is tied to a specific `OleDbConnection`. The only solution is to use TransactionScope (preferred solution) or the EnterpriseServices classes.