# How to use two databases at a time and update simultaneously in two different locations

Tags: .net, database

How to use two databases at a time? They are placed at different networks. Is it possible in .net?

Comment: are you planning to update them within a single transaction?

Comment: S @govi how to acheive this.they are at different locations[networks].

Comment: hmm.. i havent tried these, but there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063502/how-to-implement-transaction-over-multiple-databases and the whole bunch of links in there. Are they helpful?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `Transaction` that spans multiple databases you can use a `TransactionScope`.

```
using (TransactionScope t = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Execute code
    t.Commit();
}
```

The `Transaction` will be promoted to a distributed transaction when necessary. You need to make sure that the [Distributed Transaction Coordinator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759136%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is installed and then everything will work without further configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Use DataMirroring concept in Sqlserver.